# Dnn 8: update user profile

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to update some user profile data from my custom module.

```
var userId = UserInfo.UserID;
var userInfo = UserController.GetUserById(UserInfo.PortalID, userId);

userInfo.Profile.SetProfileProperty("Country", "Russia");
userInfo.Profile.SetProfileProperty("Region", "Moskovskaya oblast");
userInfo.Profile.SetProfileProperty("City", "Moscow");

DotNetNuke.Entities.Profile.ProfileController.UpdateUserProfile(userInfo);

UserController.UpdateUser(UserInfo.PortalID, userInfo);
```

The first time the app starts it works. In the `UserProfile` module an updated value is displayed. (In debug `UpdateUserProfile` method runs consideraly long) But further updates have no effect on the displaued values. If I try to resave it in some minutes after it works again. I suppose there is some caching. How to disable it?

**SOLUTION**

..is here: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/533148/scope/posts/threadpage/2
It's a bug in Dnn 8. I had to clear the cache using `DataCache.ClearCache();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Entities.Profile.ProfileController.ClearProfileDefinitionCache(Me.PortalId)
```

or try this:

```
DataCache.ClearCache();
```

Comment: It doesn't cause any effect